# Android Studio build error on NTFS partition

Tags: android, android-studio-3.2

I'm having problems building apps on Android Studio. Things work fine when the project is on my ext4 partition, but when I created a new one on my NTFS, I encountered this:

> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/GradleSyncState.syncFailed must not be null
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/GradleSyncState.syncFailed must not be null
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.$$$reportNull$$$0(GradleSyncState.java)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncFailed(GradleSyncState.java)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doPopulateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:135)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:97)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:39)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:86)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The error disappeared when I restarted Android Studio, but after that I still cannot run my app (the project structure in the sidebar is not displayed properly).

I'm using Android Studio 3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Comment: Same here. My best assumption is that this is an error in Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. (By mistake, to be honest...)

Let's say you have an NTFS partition mount at /mnt/ntfs, and your project is at /mnt/ntfs/projects/project.
Your home partition (ext4) is mounted at /home, your home directory is /home/user and you have a symbolic link at /home/user/projects that points to /mnt/ntfs/projects.

The reason I (and hopefully you too) have encountered this error is that when using Android Studio's "Open Project..." option, I provided the symbolic link (/home/user/projects/project). When trying to provide the real path (/mnt/ntfs/projects/project) the gradle sync succeeded.

So to fix this for now, simply provide the real path. However, this should probably be addressed by IntelliJ or the developers of Gradle.

Comment: You're totally right, it works fine now. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Lifesaver. Couldn't find this anywhere else. Symlinks don't work on Android Studio.